# Jpgraph axis number format: Engineering notation for large numbers

Tags: php, jpgraph

I'm using jpgraph to create some plots from measured data.

Now I have a scatter-plot with large numbers on the y-axis.
I would like to change the number format to a number and exponent instead of just showing an integer. Unfortunately I did not find any solution on-line.

The y-axis has a range of 0 to 12000000. I want to display 12E6 instead of 12000000.

Is this possible? Maybe with the SetFormat?